# How to escape colon char in sequelize when using raw query with parameters

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm new to the world of sequelize. Let's say I need to run a query (on postgres) like this one:

```
select to_char(column1, 'HH:MM:SS') from table1 where param1 = :param
```

Using sequelize I have to setup the raw query like this:

```
db.sequelize.query(query, { replacements: { param: 'whatever' }, type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }).then((list) => { ... });
```

I'm having trouble because the colon character appears in the query string; sequelize seems to interpret those colons for replacements.

Is there any special syntax I have to use, in order for sequelize to parse correctly the string `to_char(column1, 'HH:MM:SS')`?

Answer (score 7):

Hope I'm not too late but I experienced the same issue and what I did was to put the string format in the replacement. Using your example, it'll be like:

```
select to_char(column1, :format) from table1 where param1 = :param
```

And the Sequelize part:

```
db.sequelize.query(query, { replacements: { param: 'whatever', format: 'HH:MM:SS' }, type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }).then((list) => { ... });
```

I couldn't find the 'official' way to do it so this is like a tiny roundabout method.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's late, but can be useful for others who find this question.

The best approach I found is using "Bind Parameter" instead of "Replacements".
For details check "Bind Parameter" section in [Sequelize -> Raw queries](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/raw-queries.html).

For your example:

```js
const query = `select to_char(column1, 'HH:MM:SS') from table1 where param1 = $param`

db.sequelize.query(query, {
  bind: {
    param: 'whatever'
  },
  type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
}).then((list) => { ... })
```

The idea is to replace `:` by `$` and use `bind` instead of `replacements` in query options.